# Laravel Livewire: datepicker input is erased and cannot be submitted

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-jetstream, pikaday

Laravel8, Jetstream, Livewire.  Installed normally and adding usual CRUD functions.  So far so good, until I noticed the following problem after I added Alpine.js and Pikaday to the form.

- Pikaday works fine when clicked and the selected date is set to the input field.
- However, the field is set back to the original value (so it's erased when the original value was null)  about 1 second after I do something on any other parts of the form (input other fields, press the button, etc.) and the selected date cannot be saved to DB.
- If I typed in a date manually, no problem occurs and the date is saved to DB.

I'm new to Livewire and implemented my code as instructed here:
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#creating-a-datepicker

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="schedule">        
    <label for="xxxxDate">xxxx date:</label>
    <x-date-picker wire:model="xxxx_date" id="xxxxDate"/>
```

views/components/date-picker.blade.php

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <input
        x-data=
        x-ref="input"
        x-init="new Pikaday({ field: $refs.input });"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes }}
    >
</div>
```

Any clue?

Comment: There's an example on the Pikaday controller in the [official Livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#creating-a-datepicker). My guess is that `wire:model` isn't connected to the input itself, and possibly that you have `wire:ignore` on the parent element? That controller doesn't do any domdiffing as far as I know, so that `wire:ignore` directive is probably not needed.

Comment: I removed wire:ignore from date-picker.blade.php, but the result was the same.  I can't see any essential difference between my implementation and the official one.  Is there any working example with complete codes?

Comment: in the layouts make sure you're including the livewire CSS and scripts stuff. I had the same random issues. It was because I was missing those in my "master file" documented here
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart